# Is SharePoint 2010 SP1 Compatible with SQL 2012 standard Version?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-admin-center, sharepoint-administration

I have a requirement to upgrade SQL server from 2008 to SQL 2012 for my SharePoint 2010 Application.

Currently I have SharePoint 2010 SP1 version installed in a server and SQL 2008 R2 enterprise version in another server/Database server
I want to know if SharePoint 2010 SP1 is fully compatible with SQL 2012 Standard Version? I need to upgrade SQL server from 2008 R2 to 2012.

Please someone confirm this. It will be a great help.

Comment: Is there any other things need to confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SharePoint 2010 SP1 or later version is compatible with SQL 2012, please see the requirement below:

[image]

Reference:

[Hardware and software requirements (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc262485(v=office.14))

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint 2010 SP1 does support SQL Server 2012](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc262485(v=office.14)#minimum-requirements). So an upgrade is basically possible.

You noted that you want to upgrade from SQL Server 2008 (R2) Enterprise Edition to SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. This will bring you some hassle, because SharePoint Search PropertyStoreDB makes use of the DataCompression feature of SQL Enterprise Edition.

There are two ways to work around this problem:

- The supported way: Delete Search including databases before upgrade and recreate it when you are on SQL Server 2012.
- The unsupported way: Find all objects with DataCompression enabled and disable it directly in the database. [As every manual change in a SharePoint Database is unsupported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr), you will lose support on your entire farm! Reference: [Move SharePoint 2010 from SQL Server Enterprise to Standard](https://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/migrate-sharepoint-2010-from-sql-server-trial-or-enterprise-to-standard/).